# Parse .NET json Datetime in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying extract the 1472665457134 from the string /Date(1472665457134)/

but, although the regex seems correct it doesn't work, why?

```
String jsondate = "/Date(1472665457134)/";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(\\d+)(?:-(\\d+))?/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsondate);
if (matcher.find()) //false here!!
{
    Log.d("test", matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: You should escape the parentheses - they're used for grouping in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

Because you example string is so basic, and you're trying to capture just the date then just grab the numbers.

```regex
([0-9]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- grabs the substring made up of digits.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/rV5jN6/1

**Sample text**

```
/Date(1472665457134)/
```

**Sample Matches**

```
1472665457134
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Alternative

However if you also need to validate that you're getting the substring of numbers inside parenthesis directly after `date`, then this regex will do.

```
date\(([0-9]+)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note, in Java you'll need to replace all the `\` with `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\((-?\d+)\)
```

As a Java string it is:

```
"\\((-?\\d+)\\)"
```

Capturing group 1 will contain a positive or negative number that was contained within parenthesis.